# Ubuntu 14.04 dbus unable to start any daemons

Tags: ubuntu, d-bus

syslog for running `sudo invoke-rc.d dbus restart`:

```
Feb 28 22:01:45 javaprophet-desktop NetworkManager[946]: <info> caught signal 15, shutting down normally.
Feb 28 22:01:45 javaprophet-desktop NetworkManager[946]: <info> (eth0): device state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'removed') [100 10 36]
Feb 28 22:01:45 javaprophet-desktop NetworkManager[946]: <info> (eth0): deactivating device (reason 'removed') [36]
Feb 28 22:01:45 javaprophet-desktop bluetoothd[853]: Terminating
Feb 28 22:01:45 javaprophet-desktop bluetoothd[853]: Stopping SDP server
Feb 28 22:01:45 javaprophet-desktop bluetoothd[853]: Exit
Feb 28 22:01:45 javaprophet-desktop kernel: [13529.716940] init: systemd-logind main process (886) killed by TERM signal
Feb 28 22:01:45 javaprophet-desktop bluez: Stopping uarts
Feb 28 22:01:45 javaprophet-desktop bluez: Stopping rfcomm
Feb 28 22:01:45 javaprophet-desktop NetworkManager[946]: <info> (eth0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 2584
Feb 28 22:01:45 javaprophet-desktop NetworkManager[946]: <info> (eth0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 2818
Feb 28 22:01:45 javaprophet-desktop vmnet-natd: RTM_DELROUTE: index:2
Feb 28 22:01:45 javaprophet-desktop vmnetBridge: RTM_DELROUTE: index:2
Feb 28 22:01:45 javaprophet-desktop vmnet-natd: RTM_DELADDR: index:2, addr:10.0.0.10
Feb 28 22:01:45 javaprophet-desktop NetworkManager[946]: <info> Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Feb 28 22:01:45 javaprophet-desktop kernel: [13530.325668] userif-2: sent link down event.
Feb 28 22:01:45 javaprophet-desktop kernel: [13530.325672] userif-2: sent link up event.
Feb 28 22:01:50 javaprophet-desktop kernel: [13534.750063] init: network-manager main process (946) killed by KILL signal
Feb 28 22:01:50 javaprophet-desktop ModemManager[844]: <warn>  Could not acquire the 'org.freedesktop.ModemManager1' service name
Feb 28 22:01:50 javaprophet-desktop ModemManager[844]: <info>  ModemManager is shut down
Feb 28 22:01:50 javaprophet-desktop kernel: [13534.772083] init: Disconnected from D-Bus system bus
Feb 28 22:01:50 javaprophet-desktop dbus[23696]: [system] AppArmor D-Bus mediation is enabled
Feb 28 22:01:50 javaprophet-desktop bluetoothd[23705]: Bluetooth daemon 4.101
Feb 28 22:01:50 javaprophet-desktop bluetoothd[23705]: Starting SDP server
Feb 28 22:01:50 javaprophet-desktop bluetoothd[23705]: DIS cannot start: GATT is disabled
Feb 28 22:01:50 javaprophet-desktop bluetoothd[23705]: Failed to init deviceinfo plugin
Feb 28 22:01:50 javaprophet-desktop bluetoothd[23705]: Failed to init proximity plugin
Feb 28 22:01:50 javaprophet-desktop bluetoothd[23705]: Failed to init time plugin
Feb 28 22:01:50 javaprophet-desktop bluetoothd[23705]: Failed to init alert plugin
Feb 28 22:01:50 javaprophet-desktop bluetoothd[23705]: Failed to init thermometer plugin
Feb 28 22:01:50 javaprophet-desktop bluetoothd[23705]: Failed to init gatt_example plugin
Feb 28 22:01:50 javaprophet-desktop bluetoothd[23705]: Bluetooth Management interface initialized
Feb 28 22:01:50 javaprophet-desktop cinnamon-session[1947]: WARNING: Application 'cinnamon.desktop' killed by signal 15
Feb 28 22:01:51 javaprophet-desktop dbus[23696]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1' (using servicehelper)
Feb 28 22:01:51 javaprophet-desktop dbus[23696]: [system] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1' failed: Failed to execute program /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper: Success
Feb 28 22:01:51 javaprophet-desktop dbus[23696]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.UPower' (using servicehelper)
Feb 28 22:01:51 javaprophet-desktop dbus[23696]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1' (using servicehelper)
Feb 28 22:01:51 javaprophet-desktop dbus[23696]: [system] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.UPower' failed: Failed to execute program /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper: Success
Feb 28 22:01:51 javaprophet-desktop dbus[23696]: [system] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1' failed: Failed to execute program /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper: Success
Feb 28 22:01:51 javaprophet-desktop dbus[23696]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.UPower' (using servicehelper)
Feb 28 22:01:51 javaprophet-desktop dbus[23696]: [system] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.UPower' failed: Failed to execute program /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper: Success
Feb 28 22:01:51 javaprophet-desktop dbus[23696]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1' (using servicehelper)
Feb 28 22:01:51 javaprophet-desktop dbus[23696]: [system] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Failed to execute program /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper: Success
Feb 28 22:01:51 javaprophet-desktop dbus[23696]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.UPower' (using servicehelper)
Feb 28 22:01:51 javaprophet-desktop dbus[23696]: [system] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.UPower' failed: Failed to execute program /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper: Success
Feb 28 22:01:51 javaprophet-desktop dbus[23696]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.UPower' (using servicehelper)
Feb 28 22:01:51 javaprophet-desktop dbus[23696]: [system] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.UPower' failed: Failed to execute program /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper: Success
Feb 28 22:01:52 javaprophet-desktop dbus[23696]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1' (using servicehelper)
Feb 28 22:01:52 javaprophet-desktop dbus[23696]: [system] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1' failed: Failed to execute program /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper: Success
Feb 28 22:01:52 javaprophet-desktop dbus[23696]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit' (using servicehelper)
Feb 28 22:01:52 javaprophet-desktop dbus[23696]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.ColorManager' (using servicehelper)
Feb 28 22:01:52 javaprophet-desktop dbus[23696]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.UPower' (using servicehelper)
Feb 28 22:01:52 javaprophet-desktop dbus[23696]: [system] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit' failed: Failed to execute program /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper: Success
Feb 28 22:01:52 javaprophet-desktop dbus[23696]: [system] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.UPower' failed: Failed to execute program /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper: Success
Feb 28 22:01:52 javaprophet-desktop dbus[23696]: [system] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.ColorManager' failed: Failed to execute program /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper: Success
Feb 28 22:01:52 javaprophet-desktop dbus[23696]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit' (using servicehelper)
Feb 28 22:01:52 javaprophet-desktop dbus[23696]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.UPower' (using servicehelper)
Feb 28 22:01:52 javaprophet-desktop dbus[23696]: [system] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit' failed: Failed to execute program /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper: Success
Feb 28 22:01:52 javaprophet-desktop dbus[23696]: [system] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.UPower' failed: Failed to execute program /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper: Permission denied
Feb 28 22:01:52 javaprophet-desktop dbus[23696]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.UPower' (using servicehelper)
Feb 28 22:01:52 javaprophet-desktop dbus[23696]: [system] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.UPower' failed: Failed to execute program /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper: Success
```

I ran this because I had noticed this in my syslog, repeated many thousands of times:

```
Feb 28 21:49:22 javaprophet-desktop dbus[807]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1' (using servicehelper)
Feb 28 21:49:22 javaprophet-desktop dbus[807]: [system] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1' failed: Failed to execute program /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper: Success
Feb 28 21:49:22 javaprophet-desktop NetworkManager[946]: <error> [1456724962.960417] [nm-manager-auth.c:87] pk_authority_get(): Failed to initialize PolicyKit: (23) Error initializing authority: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ExecFailed: Failed to execute program /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper: Success
```

I did some research, and decided to restart dbus. I had issues where not even my network manager restarted, which is likely because it didn't load at boot, but `org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1` does not load on boot. I ran `sudo /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkitd`, and it runs fine until I close that, after which more errors appear. What's wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I found that this was the chmod of my dbus-daemon-launch-helper

```
-rwxr-xr-- 1 root root 304K Jun 25  2015 dbus-daemon-launch-helper
```

It should have been

```
-rwsr-xr-- 1 root messagebus 304K Jun 25  2015 dbus-daemon-launch-helper
```

After changing that, it seems to be working fine now.